# F# HashCode to enum conversion

Tags: error-handling, enums, f#, hashcode, bitmask

I have an enum of bit-masked error codes with a string representation and an binary int representation:

```
type ErrorCodes = 
    | NoError = 0
    | InvalidInputError = 1
    | AuthenticationFailedError = 2
    | InvalidArgumentError = 4
    | ItemNotFoundError = 8
    | UnknownError = 16
```

As I run through the program, I collect all the errors by using the bitwise OR operator (|||). So now I have something that looks like 01100. How can I print to the console: "InvalidArgumentError", and "ItemNotFoundError?"

I had an idea of just using:

```
for i = 0 to 32 do
    if ((err.GetHashCode() % 2) = 1) then
        Console.WriteLine("ErrorCode: {0}",err.GetHashCode())
```

But now I'm stuck on how to print the actual string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you decorate your `ErrorCodes` type with the `System.Flags` attribute then `.ToString` will format as a list of value names.

```
[<System.Flags>]
type ErrorCodes = ...

let errors = ErrorCodes.InvalidInputError ||| ErrorCodes.UnknownError

printfn "%O" errors
```

Answer (score 0):

If, for whatever reason, you don't want the default flags `ToString` implementation, you could do something like this:

```
let inline printFlags (flags: 'e) =
    let ty = typeof<'e>
    (Enum.GetValues ty :?> 'e[], Enum.GetNames ty)
    ||> Array.zip
    |> Seq.filter (fun (v, _) -> v <> enum 0 && flags &&& v = v)
    |> Seq.iter (snd >> printfn "%s")

printFlags (ErrorCodes.InvalidInputError ||| ErrorCodes.UnknownError)
```

Output:

```
InvalidInputError
UnknownError
```